# How to decode Reddit's RSS using Golang?

Tags: xml, go, rss, decode, reddit

I've been playing about with Go's XML package and cannot see what is wrong with the following code.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
) 

type Channel struct {
    Items Item
}

type Item struct {
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Link        string `xml:"link"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}

func main() {

    var items = new(Channel)
    res, err := http.Get("http://www.reddit.com/r/google.xml")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        decoded := xml.NewDecoder(res.Body)

        err = decoded.Decode(items)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Title: %s\n", items.Items.Title)
    }
}
```

The above code runs without any errors and prints to the terminal:

```
Title:
```

The struct seems empty but I can't see why it isn't getting populated with the XML data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program comes close, but needs to specify just a little bit more context to match the XML document.

You need to revise your field tags to help guide the XML binding down through your 
`Channel` structure to your `Item` structure:

```
type Channel struct {
    Items []Item `xml:"channel>item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Link        string `xml:"link"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}
```

Per [the documentation for `encoding/xml.Unmarshal()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal), the seventh bullet item applies here:

> If the XML element contains a sub-element whose name matches
>     the prefix of a tag formatted as "a" or "a>b>c", unmarshal
>     will descend into the XML structure looking for elements with the
>     given names, and will map the innermost elements to that struct
>     field. A tag starting with ">" is equivalent to one starting
>     with the field name followed by ">".

In your case, you're looking to descend through the top-level `<rss>` element's `<channel>` elements to find each `<item>` element. Note, though, that we don't need to—an in fact can't—specify that the `Channel` struct should burrow through the top-level `<rss>` element by writing the `Items` field's tag as

```
`xml:"rss>channel>item"`
```

That context is implicit; the struct supplied to `Unmarshall()` already maps to the top-level XML element.

Note too that your `Channel` struct's `Items` field should be of type slice-of-`Item`, not just a single `Item`.

---

You mentioned that you're having trouble getting the proposal to work. Here's a complete listing that I find works as one would expect:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
) 

type Channel struct {
    Items []Item `xml:"channel>item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Link        string `xml:"link"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}

func main() {
    if res, err := http.Get("http://www.reddit.com/r/google.xml"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error retrieving resource:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        channel := Channel{}
        if err := xml.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&channel); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        } else if len(channel.Items) != 0 {
            item := channel.Items[0]
            fmt.Println("First title:", item.Title)
            fmt.Println("First link:", item.Link)
            fmt.Println("First description:", item.Description)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd be completely explicit like this - name all the XML parts

[See the playground for a full working example](http://play.golang.org/p/fH1yP1kVLO)

```
type Rss struct {
    Channel Channel `xml:"channel"`
}

type Channel struct {
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Link        string `xml:"link"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
    Items       []Item `xml:"item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Link        string `xml:"link"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the Reddit RSS feed seem to be have changed to the `atom` type. This means that regular parsing will not work anymore. The atom functionality of [go-rss](https://github.com/ungerik/go-rss) could parse such feeds:

> ```
> //Feed struct for RSS
> type Feed struct {
>   Entry []Entry `xml:"entry"`
> }
>
> //Entry struct for each Entry in the Feed
> type Entry struct {
>   ID      string `xml:"id"`
>   Title   string `xml:"title"`
>   Updated string `xml:"updated"`
> }
>
> //Atom parses atom feeds
> func Atom(resp *http.Response) (*Feed, error) {
>   defer resp.Body.Close()
>   xmlDecoder := xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
>   xmlDecoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReader
>   feed := Feed{}
>   if err := xmlDecoder.Decode(&feed); err != nil {
>       return nil, err
>   }
>   return &feed, nil
> }
> ```